# Is there a way to resolve types by giving name(string)?

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings, redux-toolkit

I tried to see how `createSlice` from redux working, but without success.

Example:

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => state + 1,
  },
})
// The editor aware of `counterSlice.actions.increment`
```

How it works?

Back to topic, is there a way to resolve types by given name? eg:

```js
class Resolver {
   register( name, type ) {
      // Do something
   }

   get( name ) {
      // return the Type.
   }
}
// The editor should aware of the type that been registered
```

Thanks.

Comment: Titian's answer is great, but FYI the typing is simpler if you register all names at once as object properties the way that redux-toolkit does.  Then you can make use of TS mapped types to map from the input to the return type.

Comment: Yes, but I need to register them in one file, then use in another(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of do this. First of all you can't register types, types don't exist at runtime, you can register values of specific types.

Depending on how you want to register the values, there are several options:

You can have `register` return the resolver with a different type that contains the information about the newly registered type:

```
class Resolver<T extends Record<string, unknown> = {}> {
  private values = {} as T;
  register<N extends PropertyKey, V extends unknown>(name: N, type: V): Resolver<T & Record<N, V>>  {
    let self = this as Resolver<Record<N, V>>
    self.values[name] = type
    return this as any;
  }

  get<N extends keyof T>(name: N): T[N] {
    return this.values[name]
  }
}


const r = new Resolver()
  .register("A", () => "")
  .register("B", 0);


let v1 = r.get("A"); //  () => ""
let v2 = r.get("B"); // number
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

If you want to register the values in a single file, you can have register be a custom type assertion:

```
class Resolver<T extends Record<string, unknown> = {}> {
  private values = {} as T;
  register<N extends PropertyKey, V extends unknown>(name: N, type: V): asserts this is Resolver<T & Record<N, V>>  {
    let self = this as Resolver<Record<N, V>>
    self.values[name] = type
  }

  get<N extends keyof T>(name: N): T[N] {
    return this.values[name]
  }
}


const r: Resolver = new Resolver()
r.register("A", () => "");
r.register("B", 0);


let v1 = r.get("A"); //  () => ""
let v2 = r.get("B"); // number 

// Lock in the type before we export 
export const finalR = r;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmED2IBu8BOAeAKteAHgC7wB2AJjAsEhuVhERgJakDmANNAK6kDWpJAHdSAPmgBeaAG8AvuOkBYAFDRoABxaowJaNpDdEkmbOiRoOANwq1GeG2aNMWAHL5iZStAAKGJOswiAE8AaXggrgA1dxIKGF4BYTEAClIwAFt4AC5oFy5ggJzIgEocyAhAmCIAC0doOoRkNGc8ADI4eBo6VyjRcRkbNWgQeCJoCpAAM2MauvNGlHRsalp6POhIvsG1CcmAOn1DCABtNMyAXRmggMHZFUG2UdcYzxg+cKRpnFFUjOzc0oWY4uS5KVRDOxEbgYUjQWYQA5gAyIU5-c63FR3ZT3ZQ0UiMaAYHILZoYYykeBCDpNJbJYoqDB7OwOJwYZIAIgAguyuHTJOJ2ezitZlIzmY4SGz2QAhHnQAAMwpxKhGY1QAEZjIzHkQOdzhdAAPSGtR8iQC9kq0Z6ABMWr2Oo5soNxugpG46QARphoDjXQAZJDAPj1WE1eBw64R72TWgRoQRwjqWhjFRJlPQPEEyasJGwLWWIA)

Or if there is a single instance of `r` you can use interface merging to add items to an interface:

```
interface ResolverValues {

}
class Resolver {
  private values = {} as ResolverValues;
  register<N extends keyof ResolverValues>(name: N, type: ResolverValues[N])  {
    this.values[name] = type
  }

  get<N extends keyof ResolverValues>(name: N): T[N] {
    return this.values[name]
  }
}


const r: Resolver = new Resolver()

const A = () => "";
// if in another module you can use module augmentation 
// declare module "./module-with-resolver" { interface ResolverValues { "A": typeof A } }
interface ResolverValues { "A": typeof A }
r.register("A", A);

const B = 0;
interface ResolverValues { "B": typeof B }
r.register("B", B);


let v1 = r.get("A"); //  () => ""
let v2 = r.get("B"); // number
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4HsA2A3aANThwFdNkBvAWACg6BfOhHODDNTXAqKu5ZAAcowPHEjIxZCgF4qDZG07Z8REuQwBufsigQA5sAyQoAHgByyCAA9IIACYcA1hACeWGMu5rpGAHwAFCBwALYQAFzI5gA0yGCughFeqlDEvgDa5gC6AJQCNLQCAmAAFkYAdFIa6cFhWchy8Yk6TPSFyPoQYBZWthAOzm4eyTxpGoG1SeY5kQAqmfUFRbpdpFAgcWUYleqYNaEQWS2MdKe0CFggxrqR6Co8DcggEADuI9ABOWcXV2DIAIKPT4NPzIABEYO0tAA9NDkMBPKBFCAsKVoMgQlh7KQcCh3KRkAg4BtSBgUJjsbjFKR9GFwOJgJdkHRYch7BAWHA9BisTiUGDytCKXyALQvYClEV6e7QMFUeHgaDwJDvVK7DiUcH-MGRJoQYaAhStUAmZUoO7eNW+eVg7W6hL6zyGuhQcp6QzGD62sGxf45KHMS7XABCjwADFCTUrEOauCkxhRNWDgzq4g7hqHWq73UYTAFkz7kMH-Wc6Li-ngAIyPV2dMD57X+5Cs5DAmSgiFlrqSABMNfKdfzKabrJApBCACN0WdWQAZLAIJwKzYoPXIKcwLDcl4oGyCLd-Oh7g+EoN-GCgEioGuaIA)